# Lugaru game doesn't go full screen in 12.10

Tags: 12.10

When you try to go full screen for full resolution, the task panel and the unity bar stay in place. While in 12.04, the game goes into full screen. Why does this happen in 12.10? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Open bash script /usr/games/lugaru

Delete code inside and paste this code:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /usr/lib/games/lugaru || exit 1
exec ./lugaru -fullscreen
```

Comment: How do you do bash scripting?

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest answer. Open a terminal and type

```
openlugaru -fullscreen
```

or create a launcher that includes that command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer works, but removes the help manual and windowed options. A more conservative edit would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
    -h|-help|--help) exec man lugaru ;;
    -windowed) fullscreen="false" ;;
    esac
done

cd /usr/lib/games/lugaru || exit 1
if [ "$fullscreen" = "false" ]; then
    exec ./lugaru -windowed -nomousegrab ${1+"$@"}
else
    exec ./lugaru ${1+"$@"}
fi
```

To edit the lugaru script, you need privileges, so run your text editor from terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/games/lugaru
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple answer:

1.Go to the menu
2.Right-click OpenLugaru and select Properties
3.A File Properties Tab will appear. Go to Desktop Entry and type in **Command:** openlugaru -fullscreen

That's it!

***-RD***